# Rails 4 Sprockets : No such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

I'm currently in the middle of upgrading a Ruby on Rails 3 project to Ruby on Rails 4.0.
Several of my tests related to controllers are failing because specific files cannot be found when rendering the templates during the tests:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: No such file or directory
```

All these errors have the same in common, that they try to load files from the `tmp/cache` in the Rails application. This was working all fine under Rails 3.
Is something specific required for asset compilation under Rails 4 in tests?

```
# config/application.rb
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true
```

The above is not overwritten in our test environment, so I assume this remains enabled? And we used Sprockets in Rails 3 as well.

- Rails : 4.0
- Sprockets : 3.6

I'm probably missing something obvious, just can't find it...

**Error output**

```
test_0001_should show a form to upload attachments and display existing ones(AttachmentsControllerTest::#new):
ActionView::Template::Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /root/my_app/tmp/cache/assets/test/sprockets/v3.0/m7/m7YIr0duEvKhRldOP5LjpABJF7kd9H6aT5dCMyGnOl8.cache.47262198725000.3291.4516
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:278:in `initialize'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:278:in `open'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:278:in `atomic_write'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cache/file_store.rb:107:in `set'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cache.rb:212:in `set'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cache.rb:86:in `fetch'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:56:in `file_digest'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/unloaded_asset.rb:104:in `dependency_history_key'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:304:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/environment.rb:30:in `find_asset'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:92:in `[]'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:123:in `asset_digest_path'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:76:in `compute_asset_path'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb:132:in `asset_path'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:91:in `asset_path'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb:234:in `javascript_path'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:58:in `block in javascript_include_tag'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:56:in `map'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:56:in `javascript_include_tag'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:148:in `javascript_include_tag'
    /root/my_app/app/views/layouts/attachments.html.erb:2:in `block in _app_views_layouts_attachments_html_erb___457563631613762413_47262336759680'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/haml-4.0.7/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_xss_mods.rb:5:in `with_output_buffer_with_haml_xss'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/haml-4.0.7/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:52:in `capture_with_haml'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:152:in `content_for'
    /root/my_app/app/views/layouts/attachments.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_layouts_attachments_html_erb___457563631613762413_47262336759680'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:453:in `_run__64868443609262235__process_action__callbacks'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:572:in `process'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:64:in `process'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/active_model_serializers-0.9.5/lib/action_controller/serialization_test_case.rb:25:in `process'
    /root/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:472:in `get'
    /root/my_app/test/functional/attachments_controller_test.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in <class:AttachmentsControllerTest>'
```

**EDIT**
This is the file causing the error: `app/views/layouts/attachments.html.erb`

```
<%= content_for :head do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'attachments' %>
<% end %>

<%= render template: "layouts/standard_bootstrap" %>
```

The template is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
%html{lang: "en"}
  %head
    %script
      = javascript_include_tag "/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-1.8.3.js"
      = javascript_include_tag "/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"
      = stylesheet_link_tag "/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/css/flick/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css"
      = stylesheet_link_tag 'standard'
      = stylesheet_link_tag '/stylesheets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'
      = stylesheet_link_tag '/stylesheets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.min.css'
      = javascript_include_tag "standard_bootstrap_third_party.js"
    = yield :head
  %body
    #content
      = yield
```

Could it be that it's not finding one of the files in the template?
All the referenced files exist in the `/public/javascripts` folder.

Comment: "should show a form to upload attachments and display existing ones" leads me to suspect that the app is improperly using the assets helpers to display user uploaded pictures. Is this the case?

Comment: Let me verify this before editing my reply. It's a layout file throwing the problem, but I will double check this

Comment: When rendering the attachments, we use a `link_to` to link to remote URLS, that's it. The error itself is according the stacktrace thrown by the layout file for attachments

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue when using **parallel_tests**,
fixed by adding the following to `config/environments/test.rb`:

```
config.cache_store = :file_store, Rails.root.join("tmp", "cache", "paralleltests#{ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER']}")
```

as mentioned in [parallel tests wiki](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests/wiki)